# Using VHDL with the Mojo V3 FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl, ise

I was just wondering if there's any way for me to write VHDL code, that I can then upload to the Mojo V3 board?

The Mojo V3 IDE is Verilog/Lucid friendly, both languages that I'm unfamiliar with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use Xilinx ISE to build a design for the part, then use [Mojo Loader](https://alchitry.com/pages/mojo-loader) to load the bitstream into the board's flash memory. (Due to some unfortunate design decisions on the part of Embedded Micro / Alchitry, there is no way to load a design directly onto the FPGA using the Mojo's USB interface.)

If you aren't familiar with using Xilinx ISE, [here is a brief tutorial](http://www.glennsweeney.com/tutorials/mojo-fpga-tutorials/creating-a-mojo-project) on using it with this board.